# Windows: How to save a variable -(input: path) to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, environment-variables

I'm trying to save a variable to text file, but i'm failing:

```
:folder
 echo. && echo Where is your folder ?
 set /p userinputpath = Type input[Drive][Path]:
 echo "%userinputpath%" >> folder.txt   
 IF EXIST "%userinputpath%" (goto checkexe) REM goto check .exe
 echo Incorrect input & goto folder
```

Trying to save the `userinputpath` variable -> input looks like this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Subfolder\Subfolder`

If i change the variable to string, it's working.
What is the problem ?

Comment: Lose the spaces around `=` in the set /p statement - `set /p userinputpath=Type input[Drive][Path]:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use double-quotes in the `set /p`, and also check if the input is a folder, by using `dir /a-a` with operator `&&`and `||` for to `goto :label A or B`

If exist can return True in cases where the user reports a file, to ensure that the input from a folder is passed.

For `echo\ input>...` command, you can also use "dobblequotes" to avoid any potential errors that may arise if the user enters something like `&`, `|`, or another, even if accidentally, and if you need save one at time, replace `>>`to `>`.

**Obs.:** See Conditional Execution linked below!

```py
echo\ variable >> == strings output will be append to file
echo\ variable >  == overwrite string output to file (replace all content)
```

---

```py
:folder
echo; & echo;Where is your folder?
set /p "userinputpath=Type input[Drive][Path]: "

dir /b/a-a "%userinputpath%" >nul 2>nul && (
     echo;"%userinputpath%">"%temp%\folder.txt" & goto :checkexe
   ) || set /p "'=Incorrect input!"<nul & set "userinputpath="
     timeout -1 & echo; & goto :folder

:checkexe
```

---

But, what would happen if the user (always this guy) just typed `enter/retunr`? Or, suddenly choose to use a variable for the input folder?

- Like `%temp%`, `%windir%`, `%userprofile%`, `%appdata%`, etc...

In this supposed potential case, and with minimal changes to your code, I will try to:

```py
@echo off

:folder
echo; & echo;Where is your folder?
set /p "userinputpath=Type input[Drive][Path]: " || goto :folder

<con: call dir/b/a-a "%userinputpath%\*" 2>nul >nul && (
      call echo;"%userinputpath%">"%temp%\folder.txt" & goto :checkexe
     ) || ( set /p "'=Incorrect input!"<nul && set "userinputpath=" <nul
      timeout -1 & goto :folder
     )

:checkexe
```

If user only hit `enter/return` the command `set /p "userinputpath=Type input[Drive][Path]: "` will not be executed, instead, the command after operator `||` will take action in this case because `set /p` return non `0`.

And, if the user enters any variable for the path/folder input, such as `% cd%\Folder_X`, `%temp%\SubFolder_Y`, etc..., the variables will be set correctly
and saved in `%userinputpath%` using the `call` command.

To save the variable in your file, appending (`>>`) or overwriting (`>`), leave it to be done after checking that the input is a folder, thus saving the variable correctly provided in the input:

```py
First check if path/input is a folder:

<con: call dir/b/a-a "%userinputpath%\*" 2>nul >nul && (


After that, save this folder to your file:

      call echo;"%userinputpath%">"%temp%\folder.txt" & goto :checkexe
```

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

[√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

[√] **[Why does call set work differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893287/why-does-call-set-work-differently-in-a-cmd-windows-versus-a-cmd-file)**