# Using reg.exe in a script with folder containing spaces

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, windows-registry

At my company we have a tool basically letting an user to choose on which site to log to, tool that will then deploy the correct registry files containing the settings about the site the user chose.
The registry files are deployed on user machines using Microsoft Endpoint Manager on `C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg` for 32 bits machine or `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\site1.reg` on 64 bits machine.
The tool uses `reg.exe` to import the specified file and was until now loading the reg files from the path `C:\Progra~1\MyCompany\site1.reg` for 32 bits machine and `C:\Progra~2\MyCompany\site1.reg` for 64 bits machine, however due to security concerns we're now forced to use the full fixed path to the reg files instead of legacy path.

However simply replacing `C:\Progra~1` or `C:\Progra~2` by `C:\Program Files\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` doesn't work and I think that the curlprit is the space in `Program Files`

`reg import` can't load the reg files from `C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg` even when placed into quotes as our tool is already using quotes to call the `reg import` snippet, so at the end the executed command looks like `"reg import "C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg""` which throws a syntax error.

I tried to:

- Using doubles quotes such as the command ran is `reg import "C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg"` -> doesn't work, as I feel like our tool is calling `reg.exe` and then passing as a parameter `"import "C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg""` so the double double-quotes throws a syntax error.
- Escape the space in "Program Files" as `reg import C:\Program^ Files\MyCompany\site1.reg`
- Using `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` but `reg.exe` does not seem to resolve those env vars. This is the best option IMO.

So to sum up, it seems that reg.exe is having a hard time parsing the parameters when they're passed by a script. Is this documented somewhere ?
Do you have any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is not with reg.exe and thus it is not documented. The problem is with how your system handles calling the reg import. The correct syntax is indeed `reg import "path"`, so if your system adds quotes that don't belong there, that is where you need to fix things. If your system allows it, you can try to call reg import without the path, just the regfile by specifying its path as starting location. For example as batch script: `cd "c:\program files\MyCompany"` followed by `reg import site1.reg`, or a shortcut where you specify the startup directory.

Comment: As the tool is currently designed I can only specify a path to an exe and an argument. Changing directory before executing seems impossible. But I get that we're doing it wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you can specify the path to a .cmd file, you can script it.

Comment: That would mean creating a script for each site the user could choose (if he chooses site1, then the tool calls site1.cmd that will import site1.reg) which defeat the purpose of our tool that's supposed to automate this kind of process.
What I still don't get tho is why reg.exe doesn't escape caracters as any other CLI utility would do and throw a syntax error.

Comment: Try `"""reg import ""C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg"""`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here may not be the spaces but rather the way the .reg file interprets folder paths. Try adding a double backslash instead of a single backslash when referencing a location within a reg file.

Example:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"TestKey"="C:\\Program Files\\Application\\app.exe"
```

Edit: The website changed my double backslash into a single when posting so writing this out a different way.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"TestKey"="C:DOUBLEBACKSLASHProgram FilesDOUBLEBACKSLASHApplicationDOUBLEBACKSLASHapp.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the information we got so far, its obvious the mechanism in place is not ideal, but its not impossible to deal with either.

So far, I've deduced that your program calls a file and sends a parameter along with it.

It would therefor be possible to create a batch script that works as a link to fix a problem the program is wrongly creating.

If what I understand is correct, there are many .reg files in the location C:\Program Files (or its x86 counterpart)\MyCompany and the regfiles have different names.

The program has a collection of all the possible names the regfiles can have but fails to launch the correct file.

The launch sequence has the ability to enter the name of the program and parameters.

You have tried reg.exe as program and -import path_to_reg.reg as regfile and that fails.

The solution is going to be to create one or two launch batch files to act as a link between the program and the regfiles.

If you can work with just one batchfile, then it would be this:

For this example, lets assume we call it SelectSite.cmd

```
::  -- Switch to 32 or 64bit mode

    if %1==32 goto 32bit
    if %1==64 goto 64bit
    goto invalid

:32bit
    cd /d C:\Program Files (86)\MyCompany
    goto ImportReg

:64bit
    cd /d C:\Program Files\MyCompany
    goto ImportReg

:invalid
    echo The first parameter should be 64 or 32.
    goto end

::  -- Import whatever the name of the regfile is, that is the 2nd parameter.
:ImportReg
    reg import %2

:end
```

In your tool, you select as program name: `SelectSite.cmd` and
as parameter, you use: `32 "My Site.reg"` or `64 MySite.reg` where 32 or 64 indicates 32 or 64 bits, and the second parameter is the name of the .reg file. If that file has a space, you add "", otherwise, its optional.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't manage to make it work using the tool, but it does indeed work when calling the `SelectSite.cmd` manually. There's clearly a probleme with my company tool that I can't figure how to overpass.

Answer (score 0):

---

> *Using %ProgramFiles% and %ProgramFiles(x86)% but reg.exe does not seem to resolve those env vars. This is the best option IMO.*

---

Using the variable for the path of the program files folder (x86/x64) would actually be an alternative to avoid escaping the spaces in the path, but if the variable appears not to expand from input to use as a command, you can try to "force" this expansion...

To "force" the expansion of a variable (already defined) `%typed%` via input, you can try to use `call command %var%`, as it has already been mentioned to occur in the `set /p` command in this *[question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1553599/windows-how-to-save-a-variable-input-path-to-text-file/1553617#1553617)*, also trying from the `%path%` variable.

```py
call %__AppDir__%reg.exe import "%ProgramFiles%\MyCompany\site1.reg"
call %__AppDir__%reg.exe import "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyCompany\site1.reg"

:: Or, using <con: 
<con: call %__AppDir__%reg.exe import "%ProgramFiles%\MyCompany\site1.reg"
<con: call %__AppDir__%reg.exe import "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyCompany\site1.reg"
```

---

> - ***Do you have any clue ?***
> - **I think so..**

But I'm more inclined to bet that your tool was designed with a maximum string limit, since what changes is just 1 or 2 in your *`Progra~X`* path name.

Note that the attempts involved an increase in length and started to no longer work, but there is nothing to justify this, other than the use/attempt with escaping in space, and that didn't work either.

---

These are changes to your input in your tool:

```py
:: Your old command/input, total length of string input :: 
reg import C:\Progra~1\MyCompany\site1.reg              42
reg import C:\Progra~2\MyCompany\site1.reg              42

:: Your current command/input, total length of string input ::
reg import %ProgramFiles%\MyCompany\site1.reg               45
reg import C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg             47
reg import "%ProgramFiles%\MyCompany\site1.reg"             47
reg import C:\Program^ Files\MyCompany\site1.reg            48
reg import "C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg"           49
reg import %ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyCompany\site1.reg          50
reg import "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyCompany\site1.reg"        52
reg import C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\site1.reg       53
reg import "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\site1.reg"     55
```

---

If you can test in another folder containing space and whose total length is equal to 42, and see that it works, you register that the space does not interfere, and when retrying with folder name that goes up 1 character at a time, until stop working and get the limit of acceptable characters in the tool's input...

---

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not successfully escaping the space other than by using quotes around the full path when manually using `reg.exe`. I can't use quotes to surround the path in my situation as quotes are already needed surrounding the full argument such as the script executed by my company tool is `reg "import C:\Progra~1\MyCompany\site1.reg"`. Addig quotes to the path would result in `reg "import "C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg""`  and this doesn't work. That's why I think `reg` is a bit more demanding than other binaries regarding arguments syntax...

Comment: Whats happen if you try: `reg import \"C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg\"` ..?

Comment: I'm thinking that your tool is applying a previous treatment to the strings before passing it to the interpreter, then the escape would not be for cmd, but for the language that was used to write it.

Comment: Maybe: `reg "import \"C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg\""` or: `Call "%__AppDir__%reg.exe import \"%ProgramFiles%\MyCompany\site1.reg\""`

Comment: Well, from what I understand your tool causes the limitation and it is not an event that can be characterized as a failure in the `Reg Import` command. Your tool would have to be redone and ported to your current needs.

Comment: My last message was sent too fast. I'm sorry. Neither of this snippets are working actually. In fact, for each site to logon to, the tool relies on a XML file which contains for each site a a small amount of registry settings to apply for each site and some snippet to execute a program with a parameter. 
So for each site there is a `<EXECPROGRAM>C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe</EXECPROGRAM>` and a `<EXECPARAM>"IMPORT C:\Program Files\MyCompany\[Site].reg"</EXECPARAM>`. The parameters in those registry files can't be put into the XML. So you're right, the tool is outdated.

Comment: For xml scaping you can try this: **[`&quot;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/8177207)** like i say: *...then the escape would not be for cmd, but for the language that was used to write it..*

Comment: `reg "import &quot;C:\Program Files\MyCompany\site1.reg&quot;"` or: `Call "%__AppDir__%reg.exe import &quot;%ProgramFiles%\MyCompany\site1.reg&quot;"`